# phpcassa creating column family

Tags: cassandra, phpcassa

I get a very strange error when creating `column family` with `phpcassa`, here is my code:

```
    $sys = new SystemManager("127.0.0.1:9160");

    $attr = array("comparator" => "UTF8Type");

    $data = $sys->create_column_family("my_key_space", "user_likes", $attr);
```

So i'm not actually sure if it's a valid code, but i am quite sure it is, so this is the error i get:
`TTransportException [ 0 ]: TSocket: timed out reading 4 bytes from 127.0.0.1:9160`

And i get this error after a really long loading, maybe 30-60 secs, but any other code like retrieving or inserting data works perfectly, so what could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the attribute name should be `"comparator_type"` instead of `"comparator"`.

As for why the server isn't responding, you'll probably find an Exception or stack trace in your Cassandra logs.  If you're using an up-to-date version of Cassandra (like 1.1.5 or 1.1.6), I suggest opening a ticket in the [Cassandra JIRA](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA), because it should be returning an error instead of timing out.